# Protoc in Jenkins pipline

Tags: maven, jenkins, protobuf-java

I have the following step in my Jenkins file.

```
        stage('build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'maven:3-alpine'
                    args '-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2'
                }
            }
            steps {
                   sh 'mvn clean package -B -DskipTests'
            }
            post {
                always {
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'target/*.jar', fingerprint: true
                }
            }
        }
```

My pipeline is always failing with this error message

```
 Failed to execute goal com.github.os72:protoc-jar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.1:run (default) on project xxxxxxxxxx: Unable to execute protoc-jar for /var/jenkins_home/workspace/xxxxxxxxxxxxx_branch-147/src/main/protobuf/entities.proto: Cannot run program "/root/protoc5858550646225500048.exe": error=2, No such file or directory ->
```

It seams that maven is not able to execute the protoc (protobuf) plugin command.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved,

I changed the  `maven:3-alpine` image by `3-openjdk-8` that contains the protoc compiler.

Answer (score 0):

$HOME/.m2 - is it /home/jenkins/.m2 ?

Try to use absolute path to m2 folder.

Answer (score 0):

use maven:3-openjdk-8 image has sloved my the same problem

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29890482)